# ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server (111)

Tags: mysql, linux, remote-access, mysql-error-2003

This question is related to the following questions:

- [Can't connect to MySQL server error 111](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420839/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-error-111)
- [Trying to connect to remote MySQL host (error 2003)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713808/trying-to-connect-to-remote-mysql-host-error-2003)

I am configuring a new MySQL (5.1) server on my local machine. I need to provide remote access to the database. I did the following steps:

1. Comment `bind-address` in my.cnf:

   ```
   # bind-address      = 192.168.1.3
   ```
2. Grant privileges:

   ```
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'nickruiz'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'xxxx';
   ```
3. Set port forwarding on router (TCP and UDP, port 3306, 192.168.1.3)
4. Configure iptables for firewall

   ```
   sudo iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT

   sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 --syn -j ACCEPT

   sudo iptables-save
   ```
5. Restart mysql server `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`

When testing, I get the following:

LAN:

```
mysql -h 192.168.1.3 -u nickruiz -p
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 95
Server version: 5.1.63-0ubuntu0.11.04.1 (Ubuntu)
```

Remote:

```
mysql -h 1xx.xx.4.136 -u nickruiz -p
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '1xx.xx.4.136' (111)
```

Clearly there's something wrong that's preventing me from being able to use my global IP address.

Notes:

- I've tried testing the remote connection on the same machine and also
  via SSH from a remote machine.
- I'm not sure if my ISP has given me a static IP.

Any ideas?

Update:
telnet doesn't seem to be working.

```
telnet 192.168.1.3 3306
Trying 192.168.1.3...
Connected to 192.168.1.3.
Escape character is '^]'.
E
5.1.63-0ubuntu0.11.04.1,0g8!:@pX;]DyY0#\)SIConnection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: You don't have `skip-networking` in your my.cnf, do you?

Comment: And `telnet 192.168.1.3 3306`. If it opens any sort of prompt, the the port is listening and accepting connections.

Comment: No skip-networking in my.cnf.

Comment: Telnet didn't work. See above.

Comment: Actually, that is telnet working properly.  If you get the connected and `Escape character is ^]`, then you have _successfully_ established a connection. You won't see a MySQL prompt, but you have a raw connection to the MySQL port so it is correctly listening on that address!

Comment: But I missed that you were trying to do it with your public IP.  Try the same with the public IP and it probably won't work.  Is this  a residential ISP? It is possible that your ISP blocks 3306 entirely...

Comment: The answer has been given here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16164426/1768736

Comment: I figured out that the "bind-address" parameter is in the "/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf" file. Commented it out over there and it worked!

Answer (score 16):

Please check your listenning ports with :

```
netstat -nat |grep :3306
```

If it show

```
 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Thats is ok for your remote connection.

But in this case i think you have

```
tcp        0     192.168.1.3:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Thats is ok for your remote connection.
You should also check your firewall (iptables if you centos/redhat)

```
services iptables stop
```

for testing or use :

```
iptables -A input -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 3306 -m state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A output -p tcp -i eth0 --sport 3306 -m state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

And another thing to check your grant permission for remote connection :

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO remoteUser@'remoteIpadress' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_password';
```

Comment: If you do not see '0.0.0.0:3306' when doing the netstat command, see the answer provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16164426/1768736

Comment: `192.168.1.3` is part of the 16-bit block of [private](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) IPv4 address spaces, so not very remote unless there's a VPN.

Answer (score 6):

errno 111 is ECONNREFUSED, I suppose something is wrong with the router's DNAT.

It is also possible that your ISP is filtering that port.

Answer (score 5):

Check that your remote host (i.e. the web hosting server you're trying to connect FROM) allows OUTGOING traffic on port 3306.

I saw the (100) error in this situation. I could connect from my PC/Mac, but not from my website. The MySQL instance was accessible via the internet, but my hosting company wasn't allowing my website to connect to the database on port 3306.

Once I asked my hosting company to open my web hosting account up to outgoing traffic on port 3306, my website could connect to my remote database.

Comment: This was the issue for me, the outbound port was closed on the client machine

Answer (score 3):

```
/etc/mysql$ sudo nano my.cnf
```

Relevant portion that works for me:

```
#skip-networking
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = MY_IP
```

`MY_IP` can be found using `ifconfig` or `curl -L whatismyip.org |grep blue`.

Restart mysql to ensure the new config is loaded:

```
/etc/mysql$ sudo service mysql restart
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem trying to connect to a remote mysql db.

I fixed it by opening the firewall on the db server to allow traffic through:

```
sudo ufw allow mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

if the system you use is CentOS/RedHat, and rpm is the way you install MySQL, there is no my.cnf in /etc/ folder, you could use:
  #whereis mysql
  #cd /usr/share/mysql/
  cp -f /usr/share/mysql/my-medium.cnf /etc/my.cnf

Answer (score 0):

I have got a same question like you, I use wireshark to capture my sent TCP packets, I found when I use `mysql` bin to connect the remote host, it connects remote's 3307 port, that's my falut in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, 3307 is another project mysql port, but I change that config in `my.cnf` [client] part, when I use `-P` option to specify 3306 port, it's OK.

Answer (score 0):

i set my bind-address correctly as above but forgot to restart the mysql server (or reboot) :) *face palm* - so that's the source of this error for me!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you have special characters in password you need to wrap it in `''` characters, so to connect to db you could use:

`mysql -uUSER -p'pa$$w0rd'`

I had the same error and this solution solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error and I didn't understand but I realized that my modem was using the same port as mysql. Well, I stop apache2.service by `sudo systemctl  stop apache2.service` and restarted the xammp, `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`

Just maybe, if you were not using a password for mysql yet you had, `1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`, then you have to pass an empty string as the password

Answer (score -1):

Not sure as cant see it in steps you mentioned.

Please try [FLUSH PRIVILEGES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flush.html) [Reloads the privileges from the grant tables in the mysql database]:

flush privileges;

You need to execute it after GRANT

Hope this help!