# Can't connect to database from a remote server after setting it up to allow connections

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to allow remote connections to one of my mysql databases, but after I set everything up, I keep getting a time out error. Can you tell me if I perhaps missed a step?

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with MySQL 5.5.38-0

Here's my `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file

```
[mysqld]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
# skip-external-locking
bind-address    = 0.0.0.0
```

Once I updated the my.cnf file, I restarted MySQL and then ran the following to open TCP port 3306

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

Then saved the new rules using:

```
sudo /sbin/iptables-save
```

I can see it when I run `sudo iptables -L`

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:bootps
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             LOG level warning prefix "INPUT__"
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:mysql
```

I then created a test database:

```
> create database kentest;
```

Granted it all privileges from any host:

```
> GRANT ALL ON kentest.* TO kentest@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
```

And flushed the privileges:

```
> flush privileges
```

But when I try and connect from another box:

```
$ mysql -u kentest -h x.x.x.x -p
```

I get the timeout message:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (60)
```

I did notice that I don't see the port being used when I run

```
$ lsof -i -P | grep :3306
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong or missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the Mysql server started?

Comment: Yes, it's started. I can connect to the database just fine using the box it's installed on.

Comment: Is mysqld present when you run lsof -i -P | grep mysqld

Comment: Interesting. No, I don't get any results when I run that.

Comment: The port is right, look at the iptables rule are there any packets logged `iptables -vxn INPUT|grep 3306`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673530/error-2003-hy000-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-127-0-0-1-111

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758339/error-2003-hy000-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-111

Comment: Just in case this helps, error code 60 is OS error code  60:  Device not a stream

Comment: LHristov, I get `Bad argument INPUT Try iptables -h or iptables --help for more information.` When I run that command.

Comment: Sorry, `iptables -L -vxn INPUT|grep 3306`

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? `0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the issue. We are using CSF for our firewall and needed to add the IP to:

```
sudo vi /etc/csf/csf.allow
```

Then restart CSF:

```
$ csf --restart
```