# Unblock MySQL connections from outside

Tags: mysql, debian, firewall, iptables

I am running mysql on a debian server. I want to connect to mysql from outside but of course ports where blocked by iptables.

So in iptables I added the mysql port like this:

```
iptables -I INPUT  -p tcp --dport mysql -j ACCEPT
```

However the mysql port stays unreachable from outside. When I nmap my servers IP address the mysql port won't show up. When nmapping on the localhost it will show up.

I also granted all privileges for one user, just to be shure.

Unfortunately I still can't connect to the server using mysql.

Do you have any idea what this could be and how to fix this?

Comment: Seems more appropriate for serverfault.com.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to connect to remote MySQL host (error 2003)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713808/trying-to-connect-to-remote-mysql-host-error-2003)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your */etc/mysql/my.cnf* file and make sure the **skip-networking** option is commented or removed, add the following line

```
bind-address=TheIPServer
```

and restart the server.
This should help

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss something here... On my CentOS server, I have this tool(GUI) that you can actually block/unblock certain ports or services (like MySQL:port-3306) but I don't know if they have that on Debian. You can explore it on your system admin options.

There are plenty of reference online like the following:

1. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-web-server-firewall-tutorial/
2. http://www.lowendtalk.com/discussion/3965/leb-setup-script-for-debian-6-vps-nginx-mysql-iptables-etc