# cannot connect to remote mysql server

Tags: mysql, networking

I have installed mysql lampp on my server.
When i try to connect remotely using this command:

```
mysql -h SERVER_IP -u USER -p
```

it returns me error :

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'SERVER_IP' (110)
```

I have setting bind-address to `0.0.0.0` in `/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf` file,
I have also give this iptables rule to allow access to mysql port on `3306`

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

Nmap on local server give the following output:

`PORT     STATE SERVICE`

```
#nmap -p 3306 localhost
PORT     STATE SERVICE
3306/tcp open  mysql
```

but when nmap from outside the server network i.e using external ip, nmap give the following output:

```
#nmap -p 3306 SERVER_IP
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
3306/tcp filtered mysql
```

output from `netstat -ntulp |grep 3306`

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      17946/mysqld
```

the port is listen according to netstat but can't accept connection from outside the network (remotely)

What is wrong here?

Comment: I don't know whether you have saw it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713808/trying-to-connect-to-remote-mysql-host-error-2003

Answer (score 0):

try one thing that go to your mysql server and execute below command-

```
service iptables stop
```

Now check your connection.

Comment: mysql port is still filtered

Comment: try to connect directly from mysql server consode by "mysql -h localhost -P 3306 -uroot -p" and check if you are able to connect.