# Can't connect to database (with new user)

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have created new users (for respective sites) on our database to replace the root.
These new users only have the "Select" "Insert" (for certain tables) "Update" & "Delete" privileges to certain databases for those sites.

Once I replaced all the root user credentials on all files (containing) with the new user credentials to test, I get a "Can't connect to *database_name*".

I also tried giving this new users same privileges as the root, however that didn't help as well.

Comment: have you tried using mysql from the cmd line with the new user details?

Comment: Are your trying to connect from the same server? If not, you need to add the ip connected from to the mysql whitelist.

Comment: Can you provide any logs/errors.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs No I haven't. How do I do that? :/

Comment: @schellingerht

Yes... using the same server. nothing else was changed, but the user credentials

Comment: @Nali in your command line (cmd or terminal based on os) type mysql  -uuser_name -p and enter password when prompted :)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Just did that (used "mysql -u *usrname* -p).
Returned an ERROR 2003 <HY000>: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' <10061>

Comment: @Nali did you replace username with your mysql username? (just to make sure :) )

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs hahaha... of course man. Lol

Comment: @Nali you wouldn't believe how many times people don't haha just had to check these links to see if they help :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673530/error-2003-hy000-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-127-0-0-1-111 ||| https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713808/trying-to-connect-to-remote-mysql-host-error-2003

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs   Will check the links out, thank you.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I've tried again using cmd line with (mysql -u *usrname* -h *host* -p)..... And that worked. I don't understand how it can work via the cmd line and on the database itself, but not from the site?

Comment: @Nali hmm maybe some details in the code aren't 100% correct? Or maybe the user doesn't have read / write permissions (server-side_

Answer (score 0):

Just come across this after having the same problem. It turned out that when creating the user, I needed to specify '%' for the host name, e.g.:

```
CREATE USER 'testuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'testuserpassword'
```

Initially I'd used 'localhost' and although this successfully created the user, I couldn't make a connection (from Kotlin in this case) using those credentials.

Comment: Op is facing privileges problem with new mysql user not connection problem.

Comment: @EngineerCoder Op said 'Once I replaced all the root user credentials on all files (containing) with the new user credentials to test, I get a "Can't connect to database_name"', which sounds like a connection problem