# How to use python to connect mysql via ip address?

Tags: python, mysql

I want to try to use python to connect to MySQL database.

Connecting to localhost works fine but I can not connect to MySQL database via ip address.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import MySQLdb


db = MySQLdb.connect(host="My Computer IP",
    user="root", passwd="606", db="testdb",port=3306)
cursor = db.cursor()


cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table1")


results = cursor.fetchall()


for record in results:
  col1 = record[0]
  col2 = record[1]
  print "%s, %s" % (col1, col2)


db.close()
```

The error is like this:

> OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'My
>   Computer IP' (111)")

I found that someone who also has asked the similar question on stackoverflow --> [Can't connect to MySQL server error 111](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420839/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-error-111)

I have tried this method but it still doesn't work.

I don't have the line skip-networking in the document "my.cnf" originally.

So basically, mysql should not listen only 127.0.0.1. 
In theory, mysql can listen any IP and I also set the port 3306 to be allowed in my computer.

Does anyone has some suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This answer works for me: [Trying to connect to remote MySQL host (error 2003)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713808/trying-to-connect-to-remote-mysql-host-error-2003)

I got the same error, when I connected db using `localhost`, connection was OK. But using ip `114.***.***.***`, from another pc, or from the db server itself, were all failed. And I can ping this ip from another pc.

My error was caused by an intermediate router, when I wanted to access the db via ip (not `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`), the connection request was sent to the router, then forwarded to the db server. And the router didn't have forwarding rules about that.

So I added a rule to the router by its config page, then connected the db successfully.